# jQuery : how to get array value from array key

Tags: jquery, arrays

Say I have an array :

```
var courseArray = array('0.15' => '10 Unités', '0.20' => '20 Unités', '0.30' => '30 Unités');
```

Now I want to to corresponding value from this array if I know the key.

Something like will do ?

```
var courseArray = array('0.15' => '10 Unités', '0.20' => '20 Unités', '0.30' => '30 Unités');
var courseKey = $( "#amount" ).val();
var courseValue = courseArray[courseKey];
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is that a _valid_ array? Google `Objects in Javascript`

Comment: `var courseArray = {'0.15':'10 Unités', '0.20' :'20 Unités', '0.30':'30 Unités'};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code .

Array you have created is not valid;

you need to create JSON Object to get data base on key . ([LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp))

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6nz67tdg/)

```
var courseArray = {'0.15':'10 Unités', '0.20':'20 Unités', '0.30':'30 Unités'};
alert(courseArray['0.15']);
```

Comment: @Jeremy Happy to help you :)